# Внешние поля в Entity (Android, room)

Tags: java, android, android-room, room

Есть модель:

```
@Entity
public class MyModel{
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String field1;
    private int foreignKey;
    private String fieldTable2;
    // Далее геттеры и сеттеры.
}
```

Поля `id` и `field1` должны быть частью таблицы `MyModel`. Но, поле `fieldTable2` заполняется через `INNER JOIN` в запросе на основании поля `foreignKey`.

Если оставить всё как есть, в таблице `MyModel будет создано поле`fieldTable2`, что приведёт к денормализации структуры данных.

Вопрос. Как сделать чтобы поле `fieldTable2` осталось в классе сущности и при этом не создавалось в таблице?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут два варианта:

1) положить ответственность за содержимое fieldTable2 на себя, прописав над ним аннотацию @Ignore. Поле в бд не будет, но и получая из бд экземпляр MyModel это поле будет пустым

2) Надстроить объект с Relation. Примерно так:

```
@Entity
public class MyModel{
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String field1;
    private int foreignKey;
}

public class MyModelWithField{
    @Embended
    public MyModel model;
    @Relation(parentColumn = "foreignKey", entityColumn = "key")
    public AnotherEntity field; // или public List<AnotherEntity> field; если 1 ко многим
}
```

Где `AnotherEntity` - это `Entity` для той таблицы, из которой выбираете по ключу данные

Теперь можно сделать вот такой запрос из DAO

```
@Query("select * from MyModel where *параметры*")
List<MyModelWithField> getBy(*параметры*)
```

По типу возвращаемого значения рум поймет, что вам нужно помимо таблицы MyModel притянуть еще и данные из другой таблицы.

Еще ремарка - нельзя использовать Relation внутри Entity. А то есть такой соблазн, по себе знаю =)